# How to get My Purchase Class to map to a Specific ApplicationUser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

Here is the Idea.  When an Admin is logged on they can pull up a list of all of the users.It will give the options for edit, details, delete like normal but I have added a link to Purchases like so:

```
    @model IEnumerable<IdentitySample.Models.ApplicationUser>

    @{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }
      <div class="col-12 backgroundImg">
        <div class="navbarSpace">
    <div class="col-12 formBackground">
       <h2 class="formHeader">List of Users</h2>

        <h4 class="formText">
            @Html.ActionLink("Create New ", "Create")
        </h4>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FavStrain)
                </th>
                <th>

                </th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FavStrain)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id 
         }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = 
          item.Id }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = 
        item.Id }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Purchases", "PurchaseIndex", new { 
        id = item.Id})

                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
             </table>
          </div>
        </div>
             </div>enter code here
```

When you click the Purchases link it takes you to the PurchaseIndex page which looks like this:
[Purchase List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bVS3.png)

```
       @model IEnumerable<IdentitySample.Models.Purchases>

        @{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
      }
      <div class="col-12 backgroundImg navbarSpace">
        <div class="col-12 formBackground">
    <h2 class="formHeader">Index</h2>
    <hr />
    <div class="formHeaderSmall">
        Total Points <br />
        @Model.Sum(i => i.Points) </div>
    <p class="formText">
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "CreatePurchase")
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Points)
            </th>

            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Points)
                </td>

                <td></td>
            </tr>
        }
     </table>
    <p class="formText">
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
     </div>
     </div>
```

It gives a list of Purchases and gives the total points that is why i didnt include a details page.  Everything works right EXCEPT for the fact that the Purchases do not map to a specific user.  If I create a new user and click Purchases it brings up a list of all of the purchases, not just the purchases specific for that user. How do I get a Purchase to map to a Specific User?

I have created a Purchases class that looks like this:

```
  public class Purchases
{
    [Key]
    public int PurchaseId { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Product Name")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
   [Range(0,5)]
    [Display(Name = "Points")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public int Points { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Users { get; set; }
}
```

My ApplicationUser Class looks like this:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Display(Name ="Favorite Strain")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string FavStrain { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Purchases> Purchase { get; set; }
```

Now up to this point the Database is registering the Foreign Key of the Purchases Class to the ApplicationUser class like it is supposed to.

I can create a new purchase and display them to a list and all of the Crud Operations work just fine.
The problem is when I create a new Purchase it doesn't include the ApplicationUserId in the Database it returns a Null.

[Null Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1geUb.png)

I am pretty sure that the problem is in my Controller.  I have tried just about everything so I don't want to include the failed try's so here is the Controllers as they are now and working.

There is no need for me to include the edit or details because I am not going to give the users that access.

```
 public ActionResult CreatePurchase()
    {

        return View();
    }
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreatePurchase([Bind(Include = "PurchaseId,Name,Points,Id")] Purchases purchases)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Purchases.Add(purchases);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(purchases);
    }

    // GET: Purchases/Edit/5
    public ActionResult PurchaseIndex()
    {

        var userDetails = db.Purchases.Include(u => u.Users);
        return View(db.Purchases.ToList());
    }
```

This is my first Question on Stack Overflow so forgive me if something isn't right.

**************************************Update************************************

This is my PurchaseIndexController.  Now this returns only the user associated with the purchase.  However it is always 0 because there is no UserID.  If I try using an int? type or Guid? it gives an error.  Cannot implicitly convert type int to string.

```
           public ActionResult PurchaseIndex(string ID)
    {
        //this gets all purchases for a certain individual
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var userDetails = db.Purchases.Where(x => x.ApplicationUserId == 
   ID).ToList();
        return View(userDetails);

    }
```

Here is the CreatePurchase View

```
    @model IdentitySample.Models.Purchases

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
 <div class="col-12 backgroundImg navbarSpace">
<div class="col-12 formBackground">
    <h2 class="formHeader">Add a New Purchase</h2>
    <hr />
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
      @*@Html.Hidden("id", (string)ViewBag.UserID)*@
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ApplicationUserId)
        <div class="form-horizontal">


            <div class="col-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { 
          @class = "formText col-12" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { 
        htmlAttributes = new { @class = "col-12" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new 
      { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Points, htmlAttributes: new { 
      @class = "formText col-12" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Points, new { 
      htmlAttributes = new { @class = "col-12" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Points, "", 
      new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-
           default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div class="formText">
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
</div>
      </div>
```

I also have link in the Manage section for the users to check thier points and purchases but I don't know how to create an ActionLink for this to just get purchases associated with the user.
                  Here is the controller

```
   public ActionResult WeedPoints(string ID)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var userDetails = db.Purchases.Where(x => x.ApplicationUserId == 
    ID).ToList();
        return View(userDetails);

      }
```

Here is the Action Link now.

```
<div class="col-12 formHeaderSmall">@Html.ActionLink("My 
 Purchases/Points", "WeedPoints", "Manage")</div>
```

*********************************Update****************************************

Here is the Controllers with the View Bag reference.  The Create Purchase View has the ViewBag I just Uncommented it out.

```
 [Authorize(Roles = 
"Admin,DispensaryManager,DispensaryEmployee,DispensaryEastEmployee")]
    public ActionResult CreatePurchase(string Id)
    {
        ViewBag.UserID = Id;

        //ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
  //var userDetails = db.Purchases.Where(x => x.ApplicationUserId == Id;

        return View();

    }
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    //POST: Purchases/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = 
      "Admin,DispensaryManager,DispensaryEmployee,DispensaryEastEmployee")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreatePurchase([Bind(Include = 
      "PurchaseId,Name,Points,ApplicationUserId")] Purchases 
    purchases,string id)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.Purchases.Add(purchases);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(purchases);
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = 
   "Admin,DispensaryManager,DispensaryEmployee,DispensaryEastEmployee")]
    public ActionResult PurchaseIndex(string Id)
    {
        //this gets all purchases for a certain individual
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var userDetails = db.Purchases.Where(x => x.ApplicationUserId == 
    Id).ToList();
        ViewBag.UserID = Id;
        return View(userDetails);

    }
```

***************************Total Refactor*********************************8

Here is the new controller in its entirety.

```
    public class PurchasesController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: Purchases
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var purchases = db.Purchases.Include(p => p.Users);
        return View(purchases.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Purchases/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Purchases purchases = db.Purchases.Find(id);
        if (purchases == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(purchases);
    }

    // GET: Purchases/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Users = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "UserName");


        List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (ApplicationUser user in db.Users)
        {
            SelectListItem selectListItem = new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = user.UserName,
                Value = user.Id.ToString()
            };
            selectListItems.Add(selectListItem);
        }
        //ViewBag.ApplicationUserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", 
   "UserName");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Purchases/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific 
    properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = 
 "PurchaseId,Name,Points,TotalPoints,ApplicationUserId")] Purchases 
 purchases)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var totalPoints = db.Purchases.Sum(x => x.Points);
            purchases.TotalPoints = totalPoints;
            db.Purchases.Add(purchases);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.ApplicationUserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", 
     "UserName", purchases.ApplicationUserId);
        return View(purchases);
    }

    // GET: Purchases/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Purchases purchases = db.Purchases.Find(id);
        if (purchases == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.ApplicationUserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", 
      "UserName", purchases.ApplicationUserId);
        return View(purchases);
    }

    // POST: Purchases/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific 
      properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = 
  "PurchaseId,Name,Points,TotalPoints,ApplicationUserId")] Purchases 
  purchases)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {


            db.Entry(purchases).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.ApplicationUserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", 
      "UserName", purchases.ApplicationUserId);
        return View(purchases);
    }

    // GET: Purchases/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Purchases purchases = db.Purchases.Find(id);
        if (purchases == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(purchases);
    }

    // POST: Purchases/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Purchases purchases = db.Purchases.Find(id);
        db.Purchases.Remove(purchases);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}

Now there is a dropdown list of users to choose from when you create a new purchase.  Here is the Create View.

```
        <div class="col-12 backgroundImg navbarSpace scrollBar">
  <div class="formBackground col-12">
    <h2 class="formHeader">Edit Puchase</h2>
    <hr />
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">


            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" 
     })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PurchaseId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TotalPoints)

            <div class="col-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { 
    @class = "formText col-12" })
                <div class="col-12">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { 
     htmlAttributes = new { @class = "col-12" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new 
   { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Points, htmlAttributes: new { 
     @class = "formText col-12" })
                <div class="col-12">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Points, new { 
    htmlAttributes = new { @class = "col-12" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Points, "", 
    new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            @*<div class="col-12">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TotalPoints, 
     htmlAttributes: new { @class = "formText col-12" })
                    <div class="col-12">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TotalPoints, new { 
  htmlAttributes = new { @class = "col-12" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => 
  model.TotalPoints, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>*@

   <div class="col-12">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApplicationUserId, 
   "Users", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "formText col-12" })
    <div class="col-12"> @Html.DropDownList("Users", null, htmlAttributes: 
    new { @class = "col-12" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApplicationUserId, "", new { 
          @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

     <div class="col-12">
         <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
           <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div class="formText"> @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This creates a drop down list of users displaying their User Name.  When I select a user and hit save I get an error saying that 
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Id'.

Answer (score 0):

Is the 'Id' being passed to this method null?

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreatePurchase([Bind(Include = "PurchaseId,Name,Points,Id")] Purchases purchases)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Purchases.Add(purchases);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(purchases);
    }
```

If it is null, the userID should be included (as a hidden field) in the form you are posting. Then (once the userID is populated in the DB) you should be able to get only the purchase associated with the userID, doing something like this:

```
 var userDetails = db.Purchases.Where(x=>x.ApplicationUserId == ID).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried this and It doesn't work.  The ApplicationUserId is still null and when I go back to purchaseIndex there is no purchases.  They did register in the Database but with no AppUser Id .

Comment: Now that I think about it this was working in some form because when I went to a specific user purchases the were none.  I bet if the ApplicationUserId registered in the DB it would have worked

Comment: Thanks you have gotten me one step closer.  It is now only wanting to return a specific users purchases but it comes back as 0 because the UserId is not registering.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I think you need to include the userID field in your form in the view when you create your purchase. Then the userID will be posted to your controller action 'CreatePurchase', and should be saved to the DB. Could you post the CreatePurchase View?

Comment: Hey Guys thanks so much for you help.  Any information  you need just let me know.

Comment: My feeling is that the hidden field you have into the createPurchase View for the applicationUserID is always null, and default to zero... When a purchase is created and saved to the DB, where is the applicationUserID coming from? I can not see it in your controller action `public ActionResult CreatePurchase()`, actually I can not see a model being passed to the view either

Comment: I think that is exactly what my problem is.  There is no reference to the user Id in the CreatePurchase Post method.  The user Id is coming from the PurchaseIndex method.  I can see the GUID in the url when i navigate to the page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that the 'Create new purchase' action is not passing a user id, it is currently:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "CreatePurchase")
```

Whereas it needs to be this to pass an id:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "CreatePurchase", new { 
    id = Model.Id})
```

However this assumes that an id has been passed to the purchase index view in the model for that page, which is likely not the case but I can't tell as I can't see your purchase index action. The simplest way to pass it for you is through a viewbag, however I do not recommend using this for your site if you intend to use it seriously.  The correct way to handle data across your views would be using viewmodels.  There are a lot of tutorials available, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3

Using the CRUD implementation you have you can just pass the id to the page using a weakly type viewbag.  Your purchase index action should look something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
        {
//this checks to see if an id has been passed to the action
if (id != null){
//this gets all purchases for a certain individual
var purchases = db.purchases.Where(i => i.ApplicationUserId == id).ToList()

//this gets the user id passed to the action and sticks it in a viewbag you can retrieve later on the page
ViewBag.UserID == id;

//returns the view with the list above
return View(purchases);
}
else{
//no id was passed to the action so the list is for all purchases
var purchases = db.purchases.ToList();

return View(purchases);
}

}
```

Now in your view you need to amend the create new purchase action to include the viewbag item:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "CreatePurchase", new { 
    id = ViewBag.UserID})
```

Change your create purchase action to accept the user id you are passing:

```
 public ActionResult CreatePurchase(string id)
{
//puts the id in a viewbag to again be used by the view
ViewBag.UserID == id;

    return View();
}
```

Then on your create purchase view you need to pass the viewbag item into the model, you do this by having a hidden field somewhere inside the form:

```
@Html.Hidden("id", (string)ViewBag.UserID)
```

I'm converting the viewbag into a string because assuming your are using ASP NET identity the user id is a string and ViewBag is a dynamic object, so needs to be turned into a string before you can put it into the model.id space effectively.  This will then pass the user ID to the post action and a purchase will be created specific to the id.

Bear in mind, this is a terrible way to be doing this, the default CRUD stuff whilst handy isn't really that great for production because you are accessing models directly and you will need to use weakly typed ViewBags to transfer data.  It's error prone and insecure.

Comment: I did what you said and created a ViewBag for the Id and it still doesn't register the Id.  This is stupid if Code First was developed By Devs for Devs then Why is it that the crud scaffolding operations wont pick up on Foreign Keys.  That is stupid..  Oh and when I try making a ViewModel for Purchases for some reason when I do, It wants me to add a PurchasesViewModel Table to the Database and that is not right.

Comment: Forgive me I have only been doing this for about 3 weeks. Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: Hello Isaac, you have to make sure the id is being passed to the action in the first place, else the viewbag will be empty.  An easy way to tell given your setup is to look at the URL, is there a user id in it when you load the index page for purchases?

Comment: Another alternative you have is to generate a drop down with all users on the create purchase form page, that way you can select the user yourself when creating the purchase item and the id will be carried that way. If you would like me to show you how to do that let me know and I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: So I looked at the Url like you suggested(good Idea)  and the User Guid is being passed to the Create Purchase View and the PurchaseIndex.  So why it is not returning it ?

Comment: Thanks so much Rob you are awesome.

Comment: I feel Like I need some kind of logic in my Post method for CreatePurchases

Comment: So I thought about this for a minute.  Right now you go to a Users link that pulls up a list of users.  From there you click the Purchases link that takes you to the specific user purchases.  Form there you go to Create new and create the purchase.  As far as the drop down list for the users on the create purchase page I dont want user to have to go to a list of employees to find the purchases, just to have to go through a dropdown list of user again to create the purchase.  That is just silly... So i can just remove the create new link in the Purchase Index  and create a new link for Create

Comment: I know how to create a drop down of a class like users or purchases but the problem I have is getting the selected value to save back to the database.  So I would appreciate it if you would show me that.  This will eliminate a step for the end user.  This way they can just go to a new link like ***create a purchase*** and select from a drop down of users.  Instead of going though a list of users and selecting the purchase then creating it.  What a mouth full lol

Comment: Hello Isaac, I made a mistake in my answer, the parameter for the action should indeed be 'string id' not 'int? id' as I had it, I've amended my answer.  I've had a look at your update, in your purchase index action there is no viewbag to send the id to the page, I'm not sure if this is up to date? In your purchase index action make sure to add the line ViewBag.UserID == ID;  I could say a number of things but it's hard to know where you are.  Can you please edit your update and post your current action and view for both purchase index and create new purchase, thanks.

Comment: Sorry man I didn't post the Controllers with the ViewBags because it didn't work for me.  But I have amended my answer as you asked.  I would still like to know how to get the drop down list of users though. I really don't want to pass data to the view in a weakly typed fashion.  Every time I try to create a View Model for the Create purchase class it wants to create a table called CreatePurchaseViewModel which I know is wrong.  Why is the migrations doing this?